# Cant install ros electric from source (URL is not available)

Tags: ros, source, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I think the "packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py" file is missing and as such I am unable to install ros electric through source.

Could someone please put it back up?

-Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84896/cant-install-ros-electric-from-source-(url-is-not-available)/) by [Brian Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/7226/brian-mac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

packages.ros.org has been migrated to a new host and in the process we have had to update services.  http://prerelease.ros.org/rosinstall is an attempt to revive the rosinstall generators. It appears to be broken at the moment and we'll try to revive it when time is available.  Fuerte and earlier distributions have passed the end of their support cycle and are not supported anymore so this will be a low priority.  In addition the web service overall has been deprecated in favor of a simple command line tool [rosinstall_generator](http://ros.org/wiki/rosinstall_generator)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brian Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/7226/brian-mac/) on 2013-09-29**:
Thanks for your response.

Would it be possible for someone to update the ros-electric install from source wiki page to reflect this?

I am sure there are others that will try this method and will be forever grateful knowing that their time was not wasted.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-09-29**:
You can even update the page, just create an account on the wiki -- it's publicly editable.